# How to execute a command automatically, when the cursor rests for a while in emacs?

Tags: emacs, grep, cursor-position, ispell

How can I execute a specific command automatically, when the cursor rests for a while?

During a correction phase of my project I very frequently run a grep on the word the cursor currently positioned on. I already found a great enhancement in [Grep-o-Matic](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/GrepMode), which lets me execute a grep of the current word in my git repository. After re-assigning `grep-o-matic-repository` to `F-12` I can execute the grep with one keystroke.

But maybe I could spare even this additional keystroke? I am thinking of a combination with something that wuould almost feel like the ispell-mode: When the cursor rests for, say, 500ms then the `grep-o-matic-repository` should be executed automatically.

As a final tweak the top 4 lines in the result windows should be removed, but that's a bonus I can probably attack later.

Comment: Check out [idle timers](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Idle-Timers.html).

Comment: Whow, `run-with-idle-timer` is 90% what I want. Good.

Comment: For modifying the grep results buffer, I found that I had to do the following: `(defun jpk/grep-mode-hook () (run-with-idle-timer 0.01 nil (lambda () (with-current-buffer "*grep*" (do-stuff))))) (add-hook 'grep-mode-hook 'jpk/grep-mode-hook)`.  I needed the idle timer because the hook seems to run when the buffer is created, but it takes a while before the grep process starts filling it in.